# Iteratively export raster layers along with basemap in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

My MXD has ~50 raster layers and basemap layer (from Esri basemap). The objective is to export each raster layer + basemap layer into PNG files one by one.

In [Export to PNG](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopng.htm) documentation I am not seeing any parameter to select layers I want to export so a simple loop isn't a solution.

Thus I am looking for any guidance on iteratively exporting layers along with basemap.

Comment: A layer is a set of drawing rules for a data source. All you need to do is turn all layers but the two you want to use off. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, but that would require turning off and on 50 layers one by one. Is there a tool to which i can pass a list of layers to turn on layer?

Comment: You can write that tool in ten lines of code. With bells and whistles it's no more than 30. There are plenty of code samples in the doc for Listlayers and Layer properties. You can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use arcpy.mapping. First uncheck all layers except basemap then adjust and run:

```py
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if layer.supports("visible") and layer.name[:4] not in ("Cita","Base","Worl"):
        layer.visible = True
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\pngs\{0}.png".format(layer.name), df, df_export_width=500, df_export_height=500, world_file=False)
        layer.visible = False
```

[image]